# Input string was not in a correct format; adding Command-Parameter c#

Tags: c#, sql, string

There are some topics related to my topic however I couldn't solve my problems with them.

Each time I get same messages.

procedure :

```
USE [onmuhasebe]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[stok]    Script Date: 5.01.2017 15:34:45 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[stok]
( @cari NVARCHAR(50),
  @urun NVARCHAR(50),
  @miktar INT

 )
 AS
 BEGIN
 update stok_giris SET miktar= miktar- @miktar WHERE cari=@cari and urun=@urun

 END
```

I need the subtraction here.

```
try
{
    baglanti.Open();
    //int miktar = Int32.Parse(textBox4.Text);
    //int miktar = Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text);
    int miktar = Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text.Trim());


    SqlCommand mySqlCommand = new SqlCommand("stok", baglanti);
    mySqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


    mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cari", comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString());


    mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@urun", comboBox5.SelectedItem.ToString());

    mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@miktar", SqlDbType.Int);
    mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@miktar", miktar);

    mySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

By using `Add` and `AddWithValue` you are adding four parameters to the command even though both are `@miktar` But the procedure accepting three values; you should give the third parameter like this:

```
mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@miktar", SqlDbType.Int).Value = miktar;
```